# Selenium's PhantomJS webdriver not loading page in reactjs

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium, reactjs, phantomjs

I'm trying to test a new feature of a website. This is the only page so far built in React. When I attempt to run the test in Selenium with PhantomJS the page index loads, but the full page load never triggers.

The page body is:

```
<body>
    <main id="content"></main>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadBundleJS( jsSource){
            var bundleJSScriptTag=document.createElement('script')
            bundleJSScriptTag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
            bundleJSScriptTag.setAttribute("src", jsSource)
            if (typeof bundleJSScriptTag != 'undefined'){
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(bundleJSScriptTag);
            }
        }
        var paramsArray = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
        Object.keys(paramsArray).forEach(function(key){
            var param = paramsArray[key];
            if (param.indexOf("/")>-1){
                param = param.substring(0, param.indexOf("/"))
            }
        })
        loadBundleJS('js/bundle.0.0.2.js')
    </script>
</body>
```

When the site runs in a browser the content is appended to the main tag. However, in PhantomJS this content never gets appended and PhantomJS loads a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your code, is in WebKit browser that PhantomJS runs. PhantomJS run an old version of WebKit engine which use an older version of ECMAScript. 
ReactJS use **Function.bind** method from ECMAScript 5. 
The solution is pretty simple, you need to define the Function.prototype.bind in your code if not exist. 
** Make sure that the code is loaded **before** including react.js.

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
            return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                    ? this
                    : oThis,
                aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    if (this.prototype) {
        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    }
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
};
```

}

Code taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill